# How to fix 404 error in CherryPy if in debugging mode I get 200 OK?

Tags: python, get, http-status-code-404, cherrypy

I added new parameter and so I changed the request format. In debugging mode everything passes and I get status 200 OK but when I run my application I'm constantly getting 404.

```
@cherrypy.popargs('id')
class Application:
    def __init__(self):
        self.scores = Scoring()

@cherrypy.popargs('model', 'threshold')
class Scoring:

    @cherrypy.expose
    @authorization
    def index(self, id, model=None, threshold=None):
        application_id = int(id)
        threshold = float(threshold)
        model = int(model)
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.config.update({
            'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
            'tools.response_headers.on': True,
            'tools.response_headers.headers': [('Content-Type', 'text/json')],
            'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',
            'server.socket_port': 8080
        }
    )
    cherrypy.tree.mount(Application(), '/applications/')
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
```

Same code but without threshold parameter worked perfectly fine. I'm guessing I made some mistake in adding a new parameter.
GET request format used to look like this:

```
'http://{host}:{port}/applications/{id}/scores/{model}/'
```

And now it looks like this:

```
'http://{host}:{port}/applications/{id}/scores/{model}/{threshold}/'
```

I'm new to CherryPy so any help is welcomed.